# Linux - Install Packages Offline Without Rebuilding Or Rebooting ARM64

Tags: package-management, arm64

Firstly, I am new to Linux.

I used Buildroot to generate a Linux Image with limited capabilities that I put on an SD Card and booted an ARM64 processor with no internet access.  I am not entirely sure what type of Linux it is, though.  I now want to be able to send new capabilities to the board (via packages).  The board would then install those packages and, without rebooting, be able to utilize those new capabilities.

After doing some research on this topic I have found documentation from Buildroot that states there are some packages that would not require a rebuild, but that simply installing packages is risky because of dependencies.  I also think this assumes that you are using the Buildroot `make menuconfig` to add these packages and then run `make`.  I haven't found any information about packages that would not require a reboot to utilize.

I also came across information about downloading Debian packages and putting them onto a USB (or in my case sending them via wired connection) and then using `dpkg -i` to install them.  Unfortunately, when I type `dpkg --help` when SSHed into the board, it returns "command not found", so I don't have that capability.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I´m pretty sure you can find out what distro you installed. Please provide such details. You can check the file name of the file you use to format the sd drive, or you can run the following command in the terminal: `lsb_release`. Once you know what´s your distro, we will be able to help you in a better way because many important commands will vary from one to another.

Comment: @Rho Ok so when I type `cat /proc/version` it returns:

Linux version 4.6.0 (sdepot@sdepot-VirtualBox) (gcc version 5.3.1 20160113 (Linaro GCC 5.3-2016.02) ) #2 SMP Fri May 4 10:27:49 EDT 2018

Comment: @Rho Any help with this?